# Fault tolerance in Spark vs Dask

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, dask

I read [the following](https://dask.pydata.org/en/doc-test-build/distributed.html#known-limitations) on the **Dask** documentation in the known limitations section:

> - It [Dask] is not fault tolerant. The failure of any worker is likely to crash the system.
> - It does not fail gracefully in case of errors

but I don't see any mentions of **fault tolerance** [in the comparison with Spark](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/spark.html). These are currently the ["Reasons why you might choose Spark"](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/spark.html#reasons-you-might-choose-spark):

> - You prefer Scala or the SQL language
> - You have mostly JVM
>     infrastructure and legacy systems
> - You want an established and trusted solution for business
> - You are mostly doing business analytics with some lightweight machine learning
> - You want an all-in-one solution

My questions:

- Is Spark actually designed for fault tolerance in a manner that Dask currently isn't?
- What type of **fault tolerance** does Spark **provide** (in theory/practice) that Dask doesn't, if any, or viceversa?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That set of doc pages was *very very old* and should not have been publicly available.  I have just removed them.  Please see http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/ for up-to-date documentation.

Dask is fault tolerant to the loss of any worker.  It will fail if the central scheduler fails.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently loading around 36 million of records to DynamoDB using dask bags and I'm struggling with the fact the dask processes get frozen. I splited them into 2240 independent process in order to track each process and I can say that sometimes those small process get frozen too. I'd guess then that Dask is not Fault Tolerance at least not good enough based on my experience.

```
dask==2.30.0
```